Not Throwing NotFoundException to API Gateway - NESTJS
i have trouble.... i want API gateway catch NotFoundException, but, every time i recreate even with help by chatgpt or claude, the API Gateway didn`t catch the NotFoundException..... (sorry, i've been learning nestjs)
the errors in API Gateway:

{"context":"ExceptionsHandler","level":"error","message":"Internal server error","stack":[null],"timestamp":"2024-09-22T17:56:02.987Z"}

but, in Service, the NotFoundException show up:

{"level":"error","message":"Error NotFoundException, {"response":{"message":"User tidak ditemukan","error":"Not Found","statusCode":404},"status":404,"options":{},"message":"User tidak ditemukan","name":"NotFoundException"}","timestamp":"2024-09-22T17:56:02.986Z"}


{"context":"RpcExceptionsHandler","level":"error","message":"User tidak ditemukan","stack":["NotFoundException: User tidak ditemukan\n    at PegawaiController.getPegawaiByNIP (/app/src/pegawai.controller.ts:46:15)\n    at async /app/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/context/rpc-proxy.js:11:32\n    at async ServerTCP.handleMessage (/app/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server/server-tcp.js:67:54)"],"timestamp":"2024-09-22T17:56:02.986Z"}

This my API Gateway Controller
 @Get(':NIP')
 getPegawai(@Param('NIP') NIP: string) {
 try {
    const pegawai = this.UserService.send({ cmd: `getPegawaiByNIP` }, NIP);
    this.logger.info(`Data: ${JSON.stringify(pegawai)}`);
    return pegawai;
 catch (error) {
    this.logger.error(`mengambil error ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
    return error;
    }

this my service controller
@MessagePattern({ cmd: 'getPegawaiByNIP' })
@Get()
 async getPegawaiByNIP(NIP: string) {
 try {
    const pegawai = await this.appService.getPegawaiByNIP(NIP);
    return pegawai;
 catch (error) {
    this.logger.error(`Error di controller, ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
    if (error instanceof NotFoundException) {
        this.logger.error(`Error NotFoundException, ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
        throw new NotFoundException(`User tidak ditemukan`);
    }
    throw new RpcException({
    statuscode: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
    message: `Internal Server Error`,
       });
     }
   }

this my service db
async getPegawaiByNIP(NIP: string) {
    const pegawai = await this.prisma.pegawai.findFirst({
      where: {
        NIP: NIP,
      },
    }); // Pastikan nama field sesuai dengan schema
    this.logger.info('Data: ' + JSON.stringify(pegawai));

    if (!pegawai) {
      throw new NotFoundException(`User tidak ditemukan`);
    }

    return pegawai;

